# How to interpolate 5D data using scipy Nearest ND interpolator

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have a set of data with each point having 5 parameters ([latitude, longitude, time, wind speed, bearing]). And i want to interpolate this data.

I have implemented scipy nearest ND interpolator based on what I read from the documentation, but the data at points outside the provided data points do not seem to be correct.

Implementation

```
interp = scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator(Windspeed_Data_Array[:, 0:3], Windspeed_Data_Array[:, 3:5])
```

Where "Windspeed_Data_Array[:,0:3]" is [latitude, longitude, time] and "Windpseed_Data_Array[:,3:5]" is [windspeed, bearing].

For example when I set the test coordinates to [-37.7276, 144.9066, 1483180200] 
The raw data is shown below

```
|latitude|longitude|time      |windspeed|bearing|
|-37.7276|144.9066 |1483174800|16.6     |193    |
|-37.7276|144.9066 |1483185600|14.8     |184    |
```

I thought the output at the test coordinates should be between the two data points shown, however when I run the code:

```
test = interp(test_coords)
```

The output is Windspeed = 16.6 and bearing = 193 which seems to be wrong

Comment: Tell me if the raw data looks broken, the table showed fine in the preview.

Comment: Format the table as code, that will make it look better.

Comment: It sounds as if you should interpolate the windspeed and the bearing *separately*, as a function of the latitude, longitude and time. So two independent interpolations, with 3D input each.

Comment: @9769953 I was under the assumption this was only possible if wind bearing and windspeed were independent, and in this case i dont think they are

Comment: If they are dependent, either of them should be part of the input (x) values if you're attempting to interpolate the other. Note that `NearestNDInterpolator` shows `y` to be a *1*-dimensional ndarray, while you're giving it a two-dimensional input.

Comment: @9769953 oh ok, i see, thanks. Is there another method you would recommend if I want to interpolate both wind speed and bearing simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

That's the nature of the choosen interpolation.

Nearest interpolation interpolation will assign to the dependent variables the value found in the nearest sample

This is an example from the [NearestNEInterpolator documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator.html)

[image: nearest interpolation]

If you want to have a weighted average of multiple close neighbors I would suggest you to take a look at [LinearNDInterpolator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html).

[image: linear interpolator]

Note: Don't be seduced by the "Nearest" word hehe